# function of adding a new element to list

Tags: list

I have a problem when trying to implement a program which adds a new element to an existing list. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct person{ int v;
           struct person *next;

         };

void add(struct person *head, int n)
    { struct person *nou;
    nou=(person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    nou->next=head;
    head=nou;
    nou->v=n;
    }

int main()
{
struct person *head,*current,*nou;

head=NULL;

nou=(person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));

nou->next=head;
head=nou;
nou->v=10;


add(head,14);

current=head;
while(current!=NULL)
{ cout<<current->v<<endl;
   current=current->next;

}



return 0;  
}
```

When i run it, it appears that there is only the element with the value 10 in it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a pointer to the `head` pointer so that its value can be changed.

```
void add(struct person **head, int n)
{ 
    struct person *nou;
    nou=(person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    nou->next=*head;
    *head=nou;
    nou->v=n;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
add(&head,14);
```